# Connection String Error "Missing its statement block"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ssms, nuget-package

I am using the updated Nuget Package Manager Console in Visual Studio to scaffold  models from a database I've connected from named Sail. When I enter the connection string into the Package manager console.

```
PM> Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Sail;Integrated Security=True
```

I receive the following errors:

```
At line:1 char:12
+ Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Sail;Integrated Security=True;  ...
The Data section is missing its statement block.
```

Comment: what does `to grab all info` mean? can you show us the command run? (please avoid using screen shots if possible).

Comment: images of exceptions and code are useless

Comment: You're not specifying the usage of connection string, but probably you need to set connection string like this: `Update-Database -ConnectionString "Data Source=yourservername; Initial Catalog=Sail; Integrated Security=True" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"`.

Comment: I apologize, the usage of the connection string is to generate models from that database sail

Comment: do this is db-first using `edmx`?

Comment: This is db-first yes. Not using edmx but I will try that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer:The block below successfully generates models from the connected "Sail" SQL database.

```
Scaffold-DbContext –Connection "Server(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Sail;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Sail;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
-Provider "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" -OutputDir "Models" –Context "Sail" –Verbose -Force
```